# How to get all item same category with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

#### Hi all,

I'm building an application in `Laravel`, I want to get all item in an article category without using this Eloquent.
My code is

```
$info = Article::find($article_id);
$cate_info = $info->article_categories()->first();
if($cate_info){
    $same = Article::with(['article_categories' => function ($query) use ($cate_info){
        $query->where('articles_category.ID' ,$cate_info->ID);
    }])->where('ID' ,'!=' ,$article_id)->get();
}
```

And I get all articles. How to solve.
`Article` and `Article_Category` is in many to many relationship.
Thanks.

Comment: You want all the `articles` of any single `article_category`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all the `articles` of a particular `article_categories` you can use `whereHas` method, now suppose you have `name` as a field column in `categories` table, so you can have something like this:

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
    $category = $request->categoryName;
    //    $category = 'ABC Category';

    $articles = Article::whereHas('article_categories', function($query) use($category) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$category.'%');
    })->get();

    return response()->json(['articles' => $articles], 200);
}
```

Hope this helps.